# Alineat texto checkbox

Tags: css, checkbox

estoy empezando con CSS y no consigo alinear el texto del checkbox con el icono, este es mi código, mil gracias!!

```
.checkbox {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
background-color: brown;
justify-content: flex-start;
```

}

```
.checkbox label{
font-size: 1em;
font-family: Arial;
```

}

Comment: Hola María, bienvenida al foro, ¿puedes poner el código HTML para ubicarnos mejor? Saludos

Comment: <div class="checkbox">
                    <label for="checkbox">Receive email updates?</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox">
                </div>

Comment: Por favor agregalo en la pregunta. Usa este link para [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes conseguir con `vertical-align: middle` de la siguiente manera:

```css
label, input{
  font-size: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="texto"/>
<label for="texto">TEXTO</label>
```